# Limiting number input value in Vue with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have the following component:

```html
<input class="number-input py-1 primary--text font-weight-regular"
        :ref="'number-input-' + title"
        @keypress="onKeyPressed"
        :disabled="disabled"
        type="number"
        v-model="result"
        :min="minimum"
        :max="maximum"
      />
```

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { floatFixedNumber } from '@/common/utils'

@Component({
  name: 'NumberInput'
})
export default class NumberInput extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String }) title!: string | null
  @Prop({ type: Number }) value!: number
  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false }) focused!: boolean
  @Prop({ type: Number, default: 0 }) minAllowed!: number
  @Prop({ type: Number, default: 999 }) maxAllowed!: number
  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false }) disabled!: boolean

  get result (): number {
    return this.validateValue(this.value)
  }

  set result (value: number) {
    if (!this.disabled) {
      this.$emit('on-change', this.validateValue(value))
    }
  }

  get minimum (): number {
    return this.minAllowed === null ? 0 : this.minAllowed
  }

  get maximum (): number {
    return this.maxAllowed === null ? 999 : this.maxAllowed
  }

  onKeyPressed () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$forceUpdate()
    })
  }

  validateValue (value: string | number | null): number {
    value = Number(value)
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value
    value = value < this.minimum ? this.minimum : value > this.maximum ? this.maximum : value
    return floatFixedNumber(value)
  }

  mounted () {
    if (this.focused && this.$refs['number-input-' + this.title]) {
      (this.$refs['number-input-' + this.title] as HTMLElement).focus()
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to set maximum allowed typed number to 999. With the code above, it does set the number, however in the input field I can still type 9999, even if the max number is set to 999.

I already tried the following:

```js
get result (): number {
    const num = this.validateValue(this.value) > this.maximum ? this.maximum : this.validateValue(this.value)
    return num
  }

onKeyPressed (event:any) {
    const val = this.validateValue(event?.target.value)
    if (val > this.maximum) {
      this.result = this.maximum
    } else {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$forceUpdate()
      })
    }
  }
```

And I tried this:

```js
onKeyPressed (event:any) {
    const val = this.validateValue(event?.target.value)
    if (val > this.maximum) {
      (this.$refs['number-input-' + this.title] as HTMLInputElement).value = this.maximum.toString()
    } else {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$forceUpdate()
      })
    }
  }
```

However the user is still being able to type 9999 in the field, even though it counts only 999. How do I prevent this and allow him to type (or to see in the input field) only up to 999?

Comment: Any reason you're using @keypress? I've always used @input and @blur, which fires automatically when the internal value changes and the input are deselected. Simply use a function that does `v => this.value = Math.max(Math.min(v, this.maximum), this.minimum)` from there, and it bounds the value instantly. @input is normally enough, @blur is mostly a safeguard as you can be certain the user is finished editing the value.

Comment: @Excalibaard Actually, I didn't write it, it was written by a developer who no longer works at my workplace. And personally I also have a very little knowledge of TS. I tried your solution, wrote this function that being called @input="onInput($event)" `onInput (e: any) {
    this.result = Math.max(Math.min(this.validateValue(e.target.value), this.maximum), this.minimum)
  }` I can't set this.value since it's a prop and I can't mutate it. I tried to set result, which is the v-model, but it didn't have any effect, I was still able to write 9999 in the field.

Comment: I'm not proficient in TS either, I've only used loosely typed JS so far. 'result' looks like the correct place, but maybe the parent component is listening to `@change` instead of `@on-change`, so the value isn't used/changed higher up. The example code was just another way to do the bounding that's already present in the validateValue function, I'd separate bounding the value from typechecking it.

Comment: Well, eventually I had to rewrite this component a bit, have `result` as data property and not getter/setter, have some watchers on `result` and `value` and get rid of event bindings. Finally managed to make it work! Thanks for the help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input 
  class="number-input py-1 primary--text font-weight-regular"
  :ref="'number-input-' + title"
  @keydown="onKeyPressed($event)"
  :disabled="disabled"
  type="number"
  v-model="result"
  :min="minimum"
  :max="maximum"
/>


onKeyPressed: (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    const el: HTMLInputElement = (e.target as HTMLInputElement) ?? null;
    if (el && el.value.length > 3) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```